# JSON polyfill: JSON 2 or JSON 3?

Tags: json, polyfills

I need a JSON polyfill to support IE 7 and some IE 8 and IE 9 modes. Should I pick [JSON 2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or [JSON 3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/)? Obviously JSON 3 is a more modern implementation, but for example a site like [html5please](http://html5please.com/#json) doesn't even mention it and recommends JSON 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[HTML5 Please](http://html5please.com/#json) has updated their JSON page to include **JSON 3** as the main polyfill for use, with JSON 2 taking a backseat as the older replacement.

Answer (score 14):

I was wondering the same thing. [JSON3 says](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/):

> #### Changes from JSON 2
>
> JSON 3...
>
> - Correctly serializes primitive wrapper objects (*[Issue #28](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/issues/28)*).
> - Throws a `TypeError` when serializing cyclic structures (JSON 2 recurses until the call stack overflows).
> - Utilizes **feature tests** to detect broken or incomplete *native* JSON implementations (JSON 2 only checks for the presence of the native functions). The tests are only executed once at runtime, so there is no additional performance cost when parsing or serializing values.
>
> In contrast to JSON 2, JSON 3 **does not**...
>
> - Add `toJSON()` methods to the `Boolean`, `Number`, and `String` prototypes. These are not part of any standard, and are made redundant by the design of the `stringify()` implementation.
> - Add `toJSON()` or `toISOString()` methods to `Date.prototype`. See the note about date serialization below.
>
> [bestiejs.github.com/json3/](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/)

[HTML5 Please says](http://html5please.com/#json):

> [JSON 3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/) is a polyfill compatible with
>   nearly all JavaScript platforms. It is a drop-in replacement for [JSON
>   2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) that uses feature tests to
>   detect broken and incomplete native JSON implementations, supports
>   [asynchronous module loaders](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki) and
>   [`has`](https://github.com/phiggins42/has.js/)-aware optimizers, and is built
>   to specification standards.
>
> [JSON 2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) is an older, alternative
>   polyfill by Douglas Crockford.

Answer (score 5):

Use json2.js if you want to improve the performance of your page in IE7 (and possibly 8). I was happily using json3 for months and then I saw this question and did some research. All of the jsperf's performed 1-2x faster with json2.js in my IE7 VM.

One example:

http://jsperf.com/json-vs-jquery-json/2