# Use json pretty print in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I use this json pretty print [ http://jsfiddle.net/KJQ9K/ ] with angularJS?

Lets assume myJsonValue is

```
{a:1, 'b':'foo', c:[false,'false',null, 'null', {d:{e:1.3e5,f:'1.3e5'}}]}
```

I want to be able to use below to render pre (as shown in example)

Answer (score 128):

Angular already has the `json` filter [built-in](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter):

```
<pre>
  {{data | json}}
</pre>
```

The `json` after the pipe `|` is an [Angular Filter](https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-about-the-built-in-angularjs-filters).  You can make your own [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) if you like:

```
app.filter('prettyJSON', function () {
    function prettyPrintJson(json) {
      return JSON ? JSON.stringify(json, null, '  ') : 'your browser doesnt support JSON so cant pretty print';
    }
    return prettyPrintJson;
});
```

To use your custom `prettyJSON` filter:

```
  <pre>
    {{data | prettyJSON}}
  </pre>
```

ES6 version from @TeChn4K:

```
app.filter("prettyJSON", () => json => JSON.stringify(json, null, " "))
```

Comment: Best answer. One line with the es6 syntax : `app.filter("prettyJSON", () => json => JSON.stringify(json, null, "  "))`

Comment: For my structure it throws  `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. I guess that's a [separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11616630/1175496)

Answer (score 19):

Another option is to turn the function into a filter...

```
app.filter('prettify', function () {

    function syntaxHighlight(json) {
        // ...
    }

    return syntaxHighlight;
});
```

HTML...

```
<pre ng-bind-html="json | prettify"></pre>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSTe8/

Comment: Worked but I'm seeing below error message now; "Error: json is undefined syntaxHighlight@http://dev.redrum.us/scripts/app.js:25 Xa.prototype.filter/e@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:158........."

Comment: See below for a simpler answer.  The JSON object isn't in all browsers, so that's probably why it's failing.  There is a json.js shim out there somewhere.

Comment: Polyfil JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963723/json-polyfill-json-2-or-json-3

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 9):

A simpler code:

```
app.filter('prettyJSON', function () {
    return function(json) { return angular.toJson(json, true); }
});
```

Remember to use the `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.  What I consider the most "AngularJS" way is to wrap your custom object into an Angular service:

```
myAngularModule.service('myPrettyPrintService', ,myObject );
```

The inject that into a controller:

```
myAngularModule.controller('myTestController', function(myPrettyPrintService){}
```

Then inside the controller, reference the functions and sort:

```
myPrettyPrintService.syntaxHighlight();
```

Since anything defined in JavaScript, is global anyway you could technically just access it inside a controller:

```
syntaxHighlight();
```

That may screw up with unit testingt because it adds a external, undefined, dependency to your controller.

Comment: Hey, I don't think a service is the best way here.  For presentation, a filter is more appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelCole That approach is documented fairly well in a few other answers; I have no other comment on it, though.