# How do I convert this Json object into a javascript array .. Tried PaseJson with no success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My ajax result returns this Json object below , I would like to turn this into a javascript associative array to loop through it ..

`{"store_id":"10","company_id":"1","username":"tony","password":"19f060ed6b09502715175c1cdb562df8eec1070c","name":"Dbarpos1","email":"dfbarco@gmail.com","address":"2738 N Bristol St Santa Ana CA 92706 ","phone_number":"7142425639","city":"","state":"","zip":"","goals":"New 40, Up 35, Acc $1,500","return_policy":" 0 returms","drawer_drop":"after_300","drawer_option":"indiv_200","sales_tax":"8.5%","store_schedule":"","store_logo":"","group":"","created_by":"diego barco","status":"active","contact_person":"Diego Castillo"}`

Comment: javascript has objects, not associative arrays.

Comment: That is JSON data, which is already an "associative array" (also known as a hash, dictionary). You can index properties in JavaScript using dictionary notation. For example, `foo.bar` can also be invoked as `foo["bar"]`

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as a duplicate of how to parse JSON. The user is asking how to access the JSON object as an associative array, not how to parse the object.

Comment: Wait, you want to loop through the values shown above, or you want an array of objects that you can loop through?

Comment: loop through it as an associative array

Answer (score 1):

Update your ajax call to include datatype:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"edit_store_ajax.php", 
  data:{store: store_id}, 
  type:"POST", 
  success:function(result){ for (var key in result) { } },
  dataType:"json"
});
```

If datatype doesn't help, you will need to parse the String into a JSON Object. You can use jQuery.parseJSON() to help: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

```
$.ajax({
  url:"edit_store_ajax.php", 
  data:{store: store_id}, 
  type:"POST", 
  success:function(result){ result = $.parseJSON(result); for (var key in result) { } }
});
```

You can loop through it in the same way you would an associative array...

```
for (var key in json) {
  console.log(key + ":" + json[key]);
}
```

Or to get single values:

```
console.log(json["store_id"]);
console.log(json["username"]);
console.log(json.store_id);
console.log(json.username);
```

Comment: That doesnt work the way it should .. it returns every single character in the loop

Comment: @user3704664 Did you parse the JSON string into a JSON object before using this code?  If not, I'll have to rethink my comment on the question.

Comment: if his "ajax response returned the JSON object" why would it need to be parsed? obviously a String would need to be parsed but that is not what OP said...

Comment: @happytimeharry OP's comment suggest that the response is not a JSON object but a string that needs to be thrown through JSON.parse()

Comment: @villecoder sorry, what suggests that? the FIRST SENTENCE that says "My ajax result returns this Json object below" or the fact that it is not wrapped with quotes in the code snippet?.. plus it is tagged JQuery, which parses it for you automatically...

Comment: It's not working bro  ... it returns every single character

Comment: Below is the ajax code  $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".select_store").click(function() {

    var store_id = $(this).val(); 

    $.ajax({
      url:"edit_store_ajax.php",
      data : {store: store_id},
      type : "POST",
      success:function(result){

        for (var key in result) {
          
        }

      }

    });


  });

});

Comment: see the edit, use dataType:"json" to coerce it for you

Comment: it doesnt make any sense... a Fiddle would help

Comment: @happytimeharry Trust me when I say that your code works as advertised and that OP is very likely acting on a string.  See http://jsfiddle.net/7z4hh/.  First set of code acts on a string.  Second set acts on the same "object" after it has been JSON parsed.

Comment: @villecoder 10-4 buddy i just took the OP literally for what was said and showed... def a string at this point

Comment: what doesnt make sense? just add the dataType:"json" to your ajax options and see if it makes a difference. if it doesnt you can use jquery to parse the json as suggested by @villecoder... $.parseJSON(string) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(data)` in more recent browsers, and a [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963723/json-polyfill-json2-or-json3) if you support older ones.