# JSON.parse, stringify in IE 9 and below

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-9

I am working on an application that has to run on IE9 and below as well. I need a JSON.parse and stringify equivalent for this. I know that i can import json.js, but is there an inbuilt method in the browser to handle JSON strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` are supported starting with IE8 in some modes. If you need support in earlier versions of IE or in other modes, you will have to add your own implementations to your project (such as json.js).  Older IE doesn't have some other way to access this functionality.

Here's further discussion of the polyfill: [JSON polyfill: JSON 2 or JSON 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963723/json-polyfill-json-2-or-json-3)